# Find model object that encompasses another in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given an unsaved/local model object, how can I find the list of objects that already have the information of the unsaved object without having to keep a list of fields in sync?

For example, say I have this model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    hands_lost = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

And say I have already created some data in the past like this:

```
Person.objects.create(name='Luke', job='Trainee')
Person.objects.create(name='Yoda', job='Master')
Person.objects.create(name='Yoda', job='Force Ghost')
```

And then from the 'hands lost in the universe' DB I get an event telling me to "SET Luke's HANDS_LOST to 1", I would like to do something like:

```
luke = find_my_object(Person(name='Luke'))
if luke:
    luke.hands_lost = 1
    luke.save()
else:
    luke = Person.objects.create(name='Luke', hands_lost=1)[0]
```

where:

```
def find_my_object(person):
    return **MAGIC HERE**.first()
```

Expected results might be:

```
find_my_object(Person(name='Luke')) -> Luke
find_my_object(Person(name='Yoda')) -> 1st Yoda
find_my_object(Person(name='Yoda', job='Force Ghost')) -> 2nd Yoda
```

---

A possible implementation that suffers from the 'keep a list of fields in sync' problem would be:

```
def find_my_object(person):
    query = {}
    for field in ['name', 'job', 'hands_lost']:
        value = getattr(person, field)
        if value:
             query[field] = value

    return Person.objects.filter(**query).first()
```

Following up questions:

- Is this a pointless exercise, should I just keep the data coming from outside as a dictionary for as long as possible?
- What about if `Person` has a related field that I might want to include? e.g. `side = models.ForeignKey(SideOfTheForce, null=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a pointless exercise

Yes, but not for the reasons you've stated about a dictionary

It would appear to me that its just obfuscating code for the sake of it when the same can be easily achieved by just inserting a queryset where you expect to introduce this new method.

You're not achieving much by abstracting this call since you still need to pass in the same information as you would without the method.

---

For what its worth, [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) may be able to help with the example code given.

Comment: Yes, I take the point. `update_or_create` doesn't really fit my use case as my logic on the 'create' path is a bit more complicated than it is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
luke = find_my_object(Person(name='Luke'))
```

to

```
luke = find_my_object('Person', name, 'Luke')
```

and

```
def find_my_object(modelname, fieldname, value=None):
    return eval(modelname).objects.filter(fieldname='{}'.format(value)).first()
```

Comment: Sorry, I have clarified my question a little bit. Although my example doesn't show it, I am looking for a solution that finds matching objects with as much of the information as possible.

Comment: u mean like sending multiple filters ? PLS be clear. " with as much of the information as possible" sounds blur

Comment: Yes, I have included some more examples and a possible implementation that suffers from the 'keeping the list of fields in sync' issue.